# vs 2010 reading configuration settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, configurationmanager

Coding in VB.net in VS 2010.  I have:

`Imports System.Configuration` and I added a reference to System.Configuration.

When

```
**MsgBox(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sDBName").ToString)**
```

is executed, it fails, with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
sDBName is set.

What have I missed?

---

In response:

Sorry for the delay in getting back to you; other things demanded my attention.

There is no such section in my app.config file.  I added sDBName and other settings via the Settings1.settings file; these objects automatically show up in app.cong as follows:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <QuickRequest.Settings1>
        <setting name="sDBName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>xxx</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="sInputPath" serializeAs="String">
            <value>c:\yyy\Infile\</value>
        </setting>
     </QuickRequest.Settings1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reference settings in VB slightly differently than you do in C#. The easiest way is to use the settings that are part of the project and then reference it through the My namespace:

```
MessageBox.Show(My.Settings.sDBName)
```

(Note, you don't need the .ToString here because sDBName is already a string).

Since you are including a separate Settings file, you should be able to access its values by calling the Default method to get the instance and then your property off of the default:

```
MessageBox.Show(Settings1.Default.sDBName)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I typed in "My.Settings.", intellisense gave me a list but my settings were not part of it. I also tried "My.Settings.Item("sDBName")" and then I executed the program. When it got to that line I received an error as follows: "The settings property 'sDBName' was not found."

Comment: I tried your 2nd suggestion (using "Default) and that worked.  However, I would like to understand what's going on here.  Why isn't the first method working? Why isn't referencing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings working?  Thank you for your time and for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: You can't use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings because your settings aren't going into the config's appSettings section, but probably the userSettings section. As for programmatic access, you can see what's going on by clicking the "Show all files" button in the Solutino Explorer and expanding your Settings1 to see the Settings1.Designer.vb file. Open that to see the generated code that you're accessing.

Answer (score 3):

You've said that `sDBName` is set: Is the `sDBName` setting included in the config of your main application, or just in the config of the assembly that the code is contained in?

It needs to be in the config of the entrypoint assembly as this is the config loaded when your application starts.

If it is set there, then you should post your config so that we can see the setting to check for problems.

---

Update in response to comment:

In the app.config, the setting should appear in the `appSettings` section, for example:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sDBName" value="devDB"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: sDBName is set in the Settings1.settings file, and appears in the app.config file as so:    <setting name="sDBName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>devDB</value>
            </setting>

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same error you check the solution is just layers and leave a app.config file in layer form and call from the other layers

```
1-reference to System.Configuration
2-Imports System.Configuration
```

so after you call

```
As String Dim TextoConexion

TextoConexion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item ("CONNECT"). ToString
```

The error occurs because you do not see "CONNECT" for example

so is the app.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="CONEC" value="Server"/>
<add key="SERVIDOR" value="SQL2008R2"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to need to follow long procedures. The easiest way to do that is

```
`msgBox(My.Settings.sDBName)`
```

this would give you value of sDBName